# Converting from SQL to HQL

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have the following SQL query that works like a champ:

```
select u.id
from morder_item mi
join book b on b.id = ${book.id}
join book_product bp on bp.book_id = b.id
join morder mo on mo.id = mi.morder_id
join user u on u.id = mo.user_id
where mi.book_product_id = bp.id
```

I'm trying to convert this to HQL but the problem is that all the examples I see are overly simple and don't deal with joins at all.  I need to get all the user ID's but the query originates off of the MOrderItem domain.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: For the sake of someone trying to help do the conversion:

```
class MOrder {
  static hasMany = [items: MOrderItem]
  static belongsTo = [user: User]
}

class MOrderItem {
  BookProduct bookProduct
  static belongsTo = [morder: MOrder]
}

class User {
  static hasMany = [morders: MOrder]
}

class BookProduct {
  static belongsTo = [book: Book]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work with some contrived data:

```
def userIds = AnyDomainClass.executeQuery('''
   select u.id
   from User u join u.morders mo
               join mo.items mi
   where mi.bookProduct.book=:book
   ''',
   [book: book])
```